# Multiple arrows on the same plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

I want to have multiple arrows on the same plot using the list `I6`. In `I6[0]`, `(0.5, -0.5)` represent x,y coordinate of the arrow base and `(1.0, 0.0)` represent the length of the arrow along x,y direction. The meanings are the same for `I6[1],I6[2],I6[3]` But the code runs into an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I6=[[(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0)], [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)], [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)], [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0)]]

for i in range(0,len(I6)): 
    plt.arrow(I6[i][0], I6[i][1], width = 0.05)
    plt.show()
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    plt.arrow(I6[i][0], I6[i][1], width = 0.05)

TypeError: arrow() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'dx' and 'dy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to unpack the coordinates and lengths from the data matrix correctly, as

```
(x, y), (u, v) = element
```

Then, the plot can either be done with `quiver` or `arrow` as shown in these two examples below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I6 = [
    [(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0)], 
    [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)], 
    [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)], 
    [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0)]
]

# Solution with arrow
for element in I6:
    (x, y), (dx, dy) = element
    plt.arrow(x, y, dx, dy, head_width=0.02, color="k")

plt.show()

# Solution with quiver
plt.figure()
for element in I6:
    (x, y), (dx, dy) = element
    plt.quiver(x, y, dx, dy, scale=1, units="xy", scale_units="xy")

plt.show()
```

[image: arrows with matplotlib arrow function]
[image: arrows with matplotlib quiver function]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of plotting arrows in matplotlib with `arrow()`, use `quiver()` to avoid issues with list values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

I6=[[(0.5, -0.5), (1.0, 0.0)], [(0.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)], [(1.5, -0.5), (0.0, -1.0)], [(0.5, -1.5), (1.0, 0.0)]]

for i in range(len(I6)):
    plt.quiver(I6[i][0], I6[i][1], width = 0.05)
plt.show()
```

In this case, the arrows seem to be too thick and with a small modulus, you can adjust this by changing the input values of your list `I6`
[image]

Comment: There should be 4 arrows. This output is not clear to me.

Comment: @user19427842 You can change list values to increase arrow size and see clearly what is going on

Comment: I don't wish to change ```I6``` since it specifies the origin and direction of the arrow.

Comment: @user19427842 But you can change its length

Comment: Okay. According to ```I6```, there should be two arrows originating from ```(0.5, -0.5)``` with the following directions: ```(1.0, 0.0)``` and ```(0.0, -1.0)```.